# How to schedule a function to run on the main UI thread in Qt for Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, qt

I am porting a Python GTK application so it uses Qt for Python(PySide2). It implements worker threads with the Python standard `threading` module and worker threads use `Gdk.threads_add_idle()` to interact with the main GUI thread.

There are many articles on the `QThread`, but I couldn't find a simple way to do this with Qt.

I hacked and came to an ugly solution like the following.
(For the core logic only, see the `IdleRunner` class and `run_on_idle()` function.)

```
import sys
import time
import threading
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *

class IdleRunner(QObject):
    run = Signal(object, tuple, float)
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.run.connect(self.on_run)
    def on_run(self, func, args, delay):
        if delay: QTimer.singleShot(delay * 1000, lambda: func(*args))
        else: func(*args)
_idle_runner = IdleRunner()
def run_on_idle(func, *args, delay = 0):
    _idle_runner.run.emit(func, args, delay)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(windowTitle = sys.argv[0])
        self.resize(400, 300)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose, True)

        self.label = label = QLabel('aaa', alignment = Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setCentralWidget(label)

        def thread_entry():
            time.sleep(1)
            run_on_idle(lambda: self.label.setText('bbb'))
            run_on_idle(self.close, delay = 1)
        self.thread = thread = threading.Thread(target = thread_entry)
        thread.start()
    def close(self):
        self.thread.join()
        super().close()

app = QApplication()
main_window = MainWindow()
main_window.show()
app.exec_()
```

I have two questions.

1. What is the best solution to this?
2. What are the possible problems of this solution?
   (Such as a memory leak).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question for others because there has been no answer for a long time.(I posted the same question on the Qt forum but still got no answer. See [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/134970/how-to-schedule-a-function-to-run-on-the-main-ui-thread).)

1. A good solution seems to be like these. Although it's not so neat, it handles two fundamental problems using proper Qt APIs.

- Posting an event from a background thread is done by `Signal.emit()`.
- Running a code on idle time is done by `QTimer.singleShot()`.

```
from PySide2.QtCore import QObject, Signal, QTimer

class IdleRunner(QObject):
    run = Signal(object, tuple, float)
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.run.connect(self.on_run)
    def on_run(self, func, args, delay):
        QTimer.singleShot(delay * 1000, lambda: func(*args))

_idle_runner = IdleRunner()
def run_on_idle(func, *args, delay = 0):
    _idle_runner.run.emit(func, args, delay)
```

2. We are using the above solution around 6 months. Up until now, there are no known problems such as a memory leak or a performance bottleneck.
3. After 9 months, I found a more efficient solution, posting an event from a background thread by the `QCoreApplication.postEvent()`. (Now it feels less hacky.) The following is more extended example which supports keyword arguments. Also, you can easily apply this to `PyQt5` by changeing `PySide2` in the import statement into `PyQt5`.

```
from PySide2.QtCore import QObject, QEvent, QTimer, QCoreApplication

class IdleRunner(QObject):
    def customEvent(self, e):
        QTimer.singleShot(int(e.delay * 1000), e.func)

_idle_runner = IdleRunner()
def run_on_idle(func, *args, delay = 0, **kwargs):
    e = QEvent(QEvent.User)
    e.delay, e.func = delay, lambda: func(*args, **kwargs)
    QCoreApplication.postEvent(_idle_runner, e)
```