# Can PyQt dialogs be shown in all threads or processes of multi-thread/process applications?

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyqt5, multiprocessing

I have a file manager application written in `Python3` using `PyQt5` running under `Linux`. I want the ability to perform multiple concurrent file operations like copy and move.

I have tried several approaches: Python ThreadPoolExecutor and ProcessPoolExecutor;  PyQt QThread.

I am able to perform multiple concurrent operations with all of these approaches but all fail when a thread or process needs to display a QDialog for user input. An empty window is displayed and the thread or process is blocked. These dialogs are used for conditions like a copy is about to replace an existing file and it is asking for user confirmation, or it is reporting the progress of copying a large file.

This situation is unlike the more typical case of a main GUI reporting progress of workers. In this case, the main GUI program is unaware of what the workers are doing and what dialogs they need to show. I know signals and slots between threads (or pipes between processes) are possible but that doesn't seem to be practical here. The need for and the content of the dialogs are determined by the workers and the main thread/process is unaware of this.

A Qt event loop is not needed to show and handle a QDialog widget in the main GUI process yet I have not found any way to show a worker dialog unless an event loop is running in that worker. The only way I found to do that is in a QThread instance. When I do that, the event loop in one thread appears to block all threads, which defeats the whole purpose of this project.

Is there any way PyQt QDialog widgets can be created and shown in a thread or process that is not the main GUI thread or process, and without blocking all other threads?

---

EDIT: Relent95 asked for a simple example, which follows. I want to emphasize that this example omits a lot such as where the Qt event is invoked. It does not accurately show how I implemented things. For example, I do not use if/then/else statements in the FSE operation() routine. The example does not include error handling or details showing the complexity that makes some suggested approaches unattractive. It provides only a bare-bones single-threaded structure so that I can explain what I would like to achieve.

```
class FseOperation():
    def __init__(self, opcode, *args, **kwargs):
        self.opcode = opcode.upper()
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.opReturn = None
        self.reportProgress = False
    
class FileSystemEngine():

    def operation(self, op):
        if op.opcode == 'COPY':
            self.copy(*op.args, **op,kwargs)
        elif op.opcode == 'SHRED':
        # ...
    
    def copy(self, src, dest, promptForReplace=True):
        if destExists:
            if promptForReplace:
                w = PromptForReplaceWidget(parameters)
                reply, options = w.reply()
                if reply:
                    rc = self.copyFile(src, dest, op.reportProgress, options)
                else:
                    rc = NO_REPLACE
            else:
                rc = DEST_EXISTS
        else:
            rc = self.copyFile(src, dest, op.reportProgress)
        op.opReturn = rc
    
    def copyFile(self, src, dest, reportProgress=False, options):
        if reportProgress:
            pbar = ProgressBar()
        else:
            pbar = None:
         while not EOF:
            block = readFile(src)
            writeFile(dest, block)
            if pbar is not None:
                pbar.update(len(block))
    
if __name__ == '__main__':

    FSE = FileSystemEngine()

    op1 = FseOperation('COPY', 'foo.bar', 'fooBar.copy', reportProgress=True)
    op2 = FseOperation('COPY', 'file.txt', 'copy.txt', reportProgress=True)

    FSE.operation(op1)
    FSE.operation(op2)

    if op1.opReturn == 0:
        print('copy1 success')
    else:
        print('copy1 fail')
```

What I wish to do is have the FSE.operation() routine initiate operations in different tasks (threads or processes) **AND** have those tasks handle their own GUI without having to rely on the main thread/process. Respondents have explained very well that what I want to do cannot be done with Python threads or processes, nor with Qt QThreads. What appears to be possible is to perform each operation via a Python subprocess or a Qt QProcess, either of which allows code to invoke a Qt event loop and control its GUI.

Using signals and slots between worker and the main thread could work but for my specific case it does not seem to be an attractive option. I am still investigating.

Comment: Your assumption that the main application shouldn't be aware of those other threads/processes seems wrong: what if the app needs to quit during multiple tasks (that should eventually be stopped) or the user is attempting an operation that is already going to be executed? Besides, one fundamental aspect that you cannot ignore is that widgets ***cannot*** be created in any thread other than the main one (that of the application), including other processes (a process always consists of a thread at least), and a QApplication ***must*** exist in the same thread in which the widget is being created.

Comment: "A Qt event loop is not needed to show and handle a QDialog widget" is also wrong: widgets can only work properly as long as an event loop processes their events; QDialog can do that by spawning its own loop (that's what `dialog.exec()` does), by relying on that of the QApplication, or eventually by regularly calling `processEvent()` (which is conceptually an event loop). It seems like you believe that signals for worker thread are only necessary to communicate progress of that worker to the UI, but that's just a *common* case, not their only purpose: a QThread could even just run on its own.

Comment: So, no, you cannot create widgets (including dialogs) in external threads, nor you should attempt to directly access them (UI elements are not thread safe). And while you could theoretically create a further QApplication in another *process*, that is impractical if the purpose is just to show a dialog. Also note that dialogs like those you mention usually need to be modal, or at least activate on top of the program, which is not always possible if using separate QApplications (see [`activateWindow()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#activateWindow); in that case, you'd need to communicate with->

Comment: -> the main application anyway, in order to ensure that that dialog is properly activated for the main application, thus making all that completely pointless. Just create and show those dialogs in the main app, either by using QThread and signals, or by doing something similar with pipes and processes.

Comment: The dialogs should provide a GUI for managing the threads. It's their job to gather input parameters from the user, which are then used to create, initialise, and conrol the workers which carry out the tasks. Signals are then used to communicate between the workers and dialogs so as to report on progress, or allow the user to cancel, pause, or restart the tasks as needed. At the moment, you have things exactly backwards, in that you're trying to make the workers control the dialogs. Qt isn't really designed to operate that way, so you will need to re-think how your program is structured.

Comment: @musicamante You are correct. I did not state things correctly. QDialogs have their own event loop via exec_(). What I was trying to say is that there is no need to expressly start the event loop as must be done for other types of widgets and I was hoping that might be the case in another process. So it can't, which you explained very well. On the other hand, you were wrong about what I believe regarding signals and slots. They are can be used for much more than just progress reporting. I appreciate you taking the time to write your comments.

Comment: @ekhumoro I'd like the children to control the dialogs. The main thread doesn't know what children are doing, only if any are running so shutdown can be graceful. I need a way to use signals and slots that are child-thread dependent. For example, two concurrent copy operations will run the same code in different threads and emit a signal requesting an "OK to replace" dialog. Two dialogs showing different filenames are needed. That's easy. But signals from each dialog resulting from user interaction must be ignored by all but the correct child thread. I have to think about how to do this.

Comment: You have to add synchronization point between worker threads and main thread where you display gui (with Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection).

Comment: @dave I'm afraid you misunderstood what I wrote. In a more broad concept of MVC pattern (not talking about the "Model/View programming" concept of Qt here), and considering the most important OOP aspects (specifically, separation of concerns), what threads (and signals) could or couldn't do is mostly irrelevant. What matters is how they interact and their hierarchy. The very fact that you believe that the GUI (which, actually, is an abstraction of the main program) should not be aware of its worker is imprecise: it *must* know about them when necessary, and only about what is necessary for it.

Comment: @dave At least in the common context of a Qt app on which you normally (should) have control, that app *is* the "controller"; the fact that it allows its child threads/procs do their work on their own is not important, until it is. But that app must be *the* reference, and those "child workers" do not actually (nor could) "control the dialogs". They *communicate* with them, through the app, which will *then* decide what to do afterwards. Simplify: you've a printer, printing thousands of pages; you can stop it by switching off its power; The printer does not control the power switch. You do.

Comment: @musicamante I believe I understand very well what you describe. Perhaps I have failed to describe clearly what I mean and want. I have a GUI file manager that operates in a single thread. The GUI has multiple panes each giving access to files and directories. File ops for all panes are performed in a shared engine (FSE), which logs and pushes details of successful ops onto a LIFO stack to support "undo" operations. The FSE operation task/routine is aware of the details needed to carry out file operations. The rest of the code is not aware; it knows only the ultimate result of each operation.

Comment: @musicamante I want the FSE to dispatch each file op into a separate task (thread or process) for concurrency. Sometimes an op interacts with a user; for example, to confirm a copy that replaces an existing file. Code outside the file operation routine is not involved with this detail and would not need to be if Qt allowed a task to handle its own GUI. From your comments, I know Qt does not work this way. I have to use Qt the way it is, not the way I wish it were.

Comment: @musicamante One way I can do this is to use signals/slots for a worker task to interact with widgets in the main GUI thread. The signal/slot architecture needed for this is not trivial. I can elaborate if anyone is interested. Another way is to launch code in separate process (via Python subprocess or perhaps Qt QProcess) and have it report back its success or failure. The launched code can have a GUI independent of the file manager GUI thread. I am now exploring these two possibilities to decide what is best for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Don't manipulate the GUI in a worker thread. Why? In short, because Qt does not support this scenario. It's the same for most other GUI frameworks. (Musicamante has already given a good detailed explanation of this in his comments.)

So, call the `Signal.emit()` or the `QCoreApplication.postEvent()` in a worker thread, to notify the main thread and let the main thread manipulate the GUI. See [Threads and QObjects](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/threads-qobject.html) for details.

The following is an example of integrating the Python standard thread API with a Qt event loop.

```
import sys
import time
import threading
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QEvent, QCoreApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMessageBox

class CallHandler(QObject):
    def event(self, e):
        e.func()
        return True
CALL_EVENT_TYPE = QEvent.registerEventType()
_call_handler = CallHandler()
# This schedules func to be called in the main thread and is thread-safe.
def post_call(func):
    e = QEvent(CALL_EVENT_TYPE)
    e.func = func
    QCoreApplication.postEvent(_call_handler, e)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(windowTitle=sys.argv[0])
        self.resize(400, 300)

        def start_thread(i):
            dlg = None
            cv = threading.Condition()
            # This will be shared between threads and accessed with a lock.
            dlg_result = None
            def show_dlg(msg):
                # This will be run in the main thread.
                nonlocal dlg
                dlg = QMessageBox(QMessageBox.Question,
                    sys.argv[0], msg,
                    QMessageBox.Ok | QMessageBox.Cancel,
                    self, modal=False)
                def on_finished(_):
                    nonlocal dlg_result
                    with cv:
                        dlg_result = dlg.result()
                        cv.notify()
                dlg.finished.connect(on_finished)
                dlg.show()
            def entry():
                time.sleep(2)
                post_call(lambda: show_dlg(f'confirm#{i}'))
                time.sleep(2)
                with cv:
                    if dlg_result is None:
                        # The dialog was not closed.                        
                        cv.wait()
                print('entry, i:', i, ', dlg_result:', dlg_result)
                post_call(on_entry_finished)
            def on_entry_finished():
                # This will be run in the main thread
                dlg.destroy()
                thread.join()
            thread = threading.Thread(target=entry)
            thread.start()

        for i in range(2):
            start_thread(i)

app = QApplication([])
main_window = MainWindow()
main_window.show()
app.exec_()
```

As a side note, if you are interested in my personal history on this technique, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71059422/how-to-schedule-a-function-to-run-on-the-main-ui-thread-in-qt-for-python).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added comments above that explain my rationale and what I hoped for. Qt doesn't support it as you mentioned. Signals/slots is a way but, unless I'm mistaken, for my case it is not trivial. Here's an example: worker issues a signal with data that instructs the main GUI thread to build a Qt widget defined by that data, get a response from a user and send the response back to the correct one of several workers. I see ways to do this but they are not attractive. The cleanest solution for me may be to launch code in a separate process via subprocess or perhaps Qt QProcess.

Comment: @dave inter thread communication is expected to work like that if any of those threads requires that it is never blocked (which is, the GUI thread) and any of the operations *must* be directly called within the thread. One way to do it is by using a queue, continuously polled by the worker whenever it has to wait for a reply: the worker emits a signal, and wait for the queue to be filled in by the main thread with what the user "replied". I know that doing it doesn't seem immediate, but you want to work with threads, which means complexity, and that's what you need to implement.

Comment: @musicamante I've been thinking through different designs: (1) set of signals/slots for each worker assigned by the dispatcher, or (2) single set of signals/slots where workers pass a token or worker_id with the signals, returned in signals so the workers can decide which returns are for them (like TCP/IP addressing). Either approach is OK. It's the complexity of widget creation in the main thread and overhead for progress reporting that discourages me. The QProcess approach is looking more attractive; minimal inter-process communication -- only final results need to be passed back.

Comment: @dave I'm not sure I'm understanding correctly: it seems that with your first solution you want tell the worker what signals will be emitted and to what slots they should be connected; the second proposal seems to be using a "broadcast" method, with *all* workers possibly receiving the same signal. The former is quite odd, as signals should be members of the workers, you should not emit foreign signals, especially if they belong to objects at higher levels; the latter doesn't seem very effective: unrelated workers should **never** receive signals that are not related to them.

Comment: @dave, in my example code, the main window doesn't know about the information(dlg, dlg_closed, cv, etc.) on a GUI scenario implemented in a worker thread. That's exactly the pattern what you wanted. Also, a worker thread can send any data to its GUI code(controlled by the worker thread but executed in the main thread) by using the Python lambda, and reversely the GUI code can send any data to the worker thread by setting a variable thread safely. I'll update the example so it demonstrates this. Finally, I don't recommend a child process rendering its own GUI, because it's too complex.

Comment: @musicamante Perhaps I don’t understand Qt signals/slots correctly. If all workers run the same code, they connect a signal of the same name to the same slot in main, and connect a main signal of the same name to their slot. As I understand it, the slot in main does not know which worker emitted the signal unless a worker_ID is carried in accompanying data, and when main emits its signal, that signal triggers all slots connected to it – so yes, a broadcast. Not so?

Comment: @relent95 Your example is great and would work but has two problems for me: (1) widget creation is complex and that logic is required on both sides of the main/worker fence (maintenance headache #1) unless a widget can be created in a worker and passed to the main thread (not possible I think), and (2) my progress reporting requires a lot of set/get of data now carried in the widget class instance to simplify my use of static libraries with callback functions, so either much signal overhead with the main widget or duplicate data carried on each side of the fence (mtce headache #2).

Comment: @dave, It's unclear for what you want is. Please provide a minimal example as pseudo code using threads or working code not using threads.

Comment: @relent95 I added a simple example but I believe it will be misleading to the extent it omits the complexity that makes your suggestion less attractive. Just to be clear, I believe your suggestion could be extended to provide what I need. At this moment, however, it does not seem as attractive or as clean as keeping most things single-threaded and invoking only the longer running operations in QProcess where they can handle their own GUI.

Comment: @dave, in the ```copyFile()``` of your example, the file IO operations will freeze the GUI. So you can't avoid to do the file IO operations in a worker thread and to do the GUI operations in the main thread, whether you use a child process or not.

Comment: @relent95 I may not understand what you wrote correctly but I think you are saying that the I/O operations will freeze the GUI in my single-threaded case. If so, that is not correct any more than it would be for any other type of activity. The GUI is responsive for each pass of the while loop. For example, I have a Cancel button on the progress bar widget and I can cancel a copy by pressing that button. I really appreciate your interest. Perhaps we should continue this discussion by chat?

Comment: @dave, if you are seeing no freeze in a single threaded case, you are probably processing events in some way such as calling the ```QCoreApplication.processEvents()```. Try to copy a huge file(such as 10GB) in big chunks(such as 100MB). If you want such an architecture, maybe you will be interested in concurrent frameworks such as Asyncio, Trio, etc. And for a chat, sorry I don't want a chat for now.

Comment: @dave You can emit a signal with anything you want (including the worker instance itself). And, as said, if you use queues, you can directly communicate with the object itself, without any need for broadcasting. See this basic example (it's a quasi-pseudo-code, but the concept is clear): https://gist.github.com/MaurizioB/c68485f29024fd2c625bf1dcd3393f61

Comment: @relent95. You are correct, I use processEvents(). I considered asyncio but I am able to do everything I need without it; namely, progress reporting and prompt response to a cancel request. I routinely copy (and also wipe or shred) gigabyte-sized files (1 MB blocks) with no problem other than wanting multi-tasking; hence, my question to SO. Perhaps some day I may wish to use larger blocks as you suggested, then I think you are right -- asyncio or something like it may be needed.

Comment: @musicamante Thank you for the example and suggestion -- using the class instance itself as the worker ID. I had never considered doing that and then using the instance for direct communication without using a signal. Nice. I converted your pseudo code into executable code. I left it with you at github with comments. Some correction is needed before it works as desired.

Comment: @dave, I didn't suggest using big chunks. It was an experiment for observing a freezing behavior. The concurrent programming does not help this problem, because it's basically the same as your current implementation using a single thread. But it helps to write easier and cleaner code.

Comment: @relent95 I did some experimenting with block size to see how it affects copy times. I decided to adapt the block size, using 128KB when copying from one local disk to another, 512KB for copies on the same disk to reduce the number of long seeks, and 1MB for copies to network shares. This seems to work well.