# PyQt6 multithreading mixing concurrent and sequantial tasks

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt

I have a PyQt6 application in which I have implemented multithreading. I'm looking to achieve the following. Suppose I have a `step1`, which needs to be executed first. When finished, `step2` can start. However, `step2` relies on two other tasks `requirement_a` and `requirement_b`. In contrast to `step1` and `step2`, `requirement_a` and `requirement_b` are supposed to run concurrently.

I've tried implementing this using two `QThreadPool`s, but I'm not yet getting the expected results. Consider the code below:

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime
import time
from PyQt6.QtCore import QThreadPool, QRunnable, QObject, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QPushButton, QApplication


class WorkerSignals(QObject):
    """Defines the signals available from a running worker thread.

    Supported signals are:
    - started: no data
    - finished: no data
    """
    started = pyqtSignal()
    finished = pyqtSignal()


class Worker(QRunnable):
    """Worker thread"""
    def __init__(self, fun, *args, **kwargs):
        """Initialize method of the Worker thread"""
        super(Worker, self).__init__()

        # Store constructor arguments (re-used for processing)
        self.fun = fun
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.signals = WorkerSignals()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        """Execute the function with passed args and kwargs"""
        self.signals.started.emit()
        self.fun(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        self.signals.finished.emit()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.button = QPushButton('Start', self)
        self.button.setGeometry(10, 10, 100, 30)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.start)
        self.sequential_thread_pool = QThreadPool()
        self.sequential_thread_pool.setMaxThreadCount(1)
        self.concurrent_thread_pool = QThreadPool()

    def start(self):
        self.start_worker(self.step1, 'sequential')
        self.start_worker(self.step2, 'sequential')

    def start_worker(self, fun, thread_pool):
        worker = Worker(fun)
        worker.signals.started.connect(lambda: print(f'[{datetime.now()}] Started {fun.__name__}'))
        worker.signals.finished.connect(lambda: print(f'[{datetime.now()}] Finished {fun.__name__}'))
        if thread_pool == 'sequential':
            self.sequential_thread_pool.start(worker)
        elif thread_pool == 'concurrent':
            self.concurrent_thread_pool.start(worker)

    def step1(self):
        # this is a step that needs to execute first
        time.sleep(1) # do stuff
        print(f'[{datetime.now()}]   Executing step1')
        time.sleep(1) # do stuff

    def requirement_a(self):
        # this is a step that needs to execute after step1 finished, but can happen concurrently with requirement_b
        time.sleep(1) # do stuff
        print(f'[{datetime.now()}]   Executing requirement_a')
        time.sleep(1) # do stuff

    def requirement_b(self):
        # this is a step that needs to execute after step1 finished, but can happen concurrently with requirement_a
        time.sleep(1) # do stuff
        print(f'[{datetime.now()}]   Executing requirement_b')
        time.sleep(1) # do stuff

    def step2(self):
        # this is a step that needs to execute after step1, requirement_a and requirement_b finished
        self.start_worker(self.requirement_a, 'concurrent')
        self.start_worker(self.requirement_b, 'concurrent')

        self.concurrent_thread_pool.waitForDone() # wait for requirement_a and requirement_b to finish

        time.sleep(1) # do stuff
        print(f'[{datetime.now()}]   Executing step2')
        time.sleep(1) # do stuff


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Note that currently `step2` is given to the sequential threadpool, from where it sends `requirement_a` and `requirement_b` to the concurrent threadpool. This is some kind of thread nesting I suppose?
Running this code and clicking the button prints the following:

```
[2023-06-16 17:15:54.792738] Started step1
[2023-06-16 17:15:55.794494]   Executing step1
[2023-06-16 17:15:56.804084] Finished step1
[2023-06-16 17:15:56.804084] Started step2
[2023-06-16 17:15:57.817431]   Executing requirement_b[2023-06-16 17:15:57.817431]   Executing requirement_a

[2023-06-16 17:15:59.848227]   Executing step2
[2023-06-16 17:16:00.859409] Finished step2
```

The order of the steps are being executed in the way that I desire, however the "Started requirement_a", "Finished requirement_a", "Started requirement_b" and "Finished requirement_b" prints are missing. This indicates that these print statements connected to `worker.signals.started` and `worker.signals.finished` for the `worker` that is given to `self.concurrent_thread_pool`, do not seem to be executed.

I've spent quite some time on trying to fix this. I have also done quite some digging and reading in trying to find a best practice for mixing sequential and concurrent threading. Both without any luck... What am I doing wrong and how should this be done? Hopefully the community can clarify and help me on this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because there's no event loop which can process the `started` and `finished` signals emitted when the workers run in the `step2()`. You need to understand the [thread affinity](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#thread-affinity) of a `QObject`. You didn't hint Qt that the signals should be queued into the main thread.

There are many possible solutions to your problem. I'll mention just one which uses slots of the `MainWindow` as hints.

```
...
class WorkerSignals(QObject):
    started = pyqtSignal(object)
    finished = pyqtSignal(object)

class Worker(QRunnable):
    ...
    def run(self):
        self.signals.started.emit(self)
        self.fun(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        self.signals.finished.emit(self)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    ...
    def on_worker_started(self, worker):
        print(f'[{datetime.now()}] Started {worker.fun.__name__}')

    def on_worker_finished(self, worker):
        print(f'[{datetime.now()}] Finished {worker.fun.__name__}')

    def start_worker(self, fun, thread_pool):
        worker = Worker(fun)
        worker.signals.started.connect(self.on_worker_started)
        worker.signals.finished.connect(self.on_worker_finished)
        ...
...
```

Comment: Implementing this prints "qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QRunnable*'" and the started and ended messages don't get printed at all

Comment: And could you elobrate on other possible solutions?

Comment: @Teun, I fixed wrong arguments of ```pyQtSignal()``` and typos on ```print()```. See [test_thread_pool.py](https://gist.github.com/relent95/f05043544c79ac7e6c97972519396196) for the full code.

Comment: @Teun, another solution will be making the ```self.start_worker(self.requirement_a, 'concurrent')``` run on the main thread, by using the ```postEvent()``` or defining new signals on the ```MainWindow```. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73189925/1186624) for the former.